# Use Kafka to increase resilience of a new service

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, cqrs

I am working in a project that starts creating independent deployable services. The service we are creating should be resilient with an 24/7 uptime.

Some devs already created a concept regarding what technologies to use. To make sure that the service is always available Kafka should be used. For example there should be a simple application/serverless function that adds something to an collection of items. The thin layer should create a Kafka message that will be processed by the real application later on.

In the beginning this approach sound odd to me. Kafka is something to communicate between systems. But is it good to split applications even more to increase resilience for a bounded context? I guess not I thought. Because by using modern technologies the application can be very resilient. Therefore we can just create one application instead of adding a lot more complexity.

Later I understood that this approach is a CQRS like approach. By creating an application that receives the writes it will be completely separated from the reads. In this case Kafka will be used as an event system. It should maybe not delete old messages but however, I want to understand if this is a good way to go and if I am getting the things right.

What do you think about the requirements and the usage of Kafka to get a highly available and resilient application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key questions here are

**Modern Applications are resilient**

While on theory it may sound correct, there are still quite of lot of modern apps which fails miserably owing to wide range of factors like poor design, excessive load etc

If your app has zero-downtime deployment and MTBF(Mean Time Between Failures) is close to 0, then your app is resilient and you need not have to look for Kafka

**Kafka Complexity**

If for some-reason you are not able to achieve zero-down time or MTBF close to zero, Kafka is a powerful option to you. Simple reason being, you can configure Kafka listener with retry, so if your app is down for sometime, the message can still be processed after the service restarts. Additionally, you would be able to use the powerful Kafka streaming capabilities like transaction processing

But beware that Kafka only provides a total order over messages within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic.

If you have a topic with single partition, the ordering is guaranteed. If your consumer if performing well, you don't have to worry.

Also since message processing is going to be asynchronous, you will not be guaranteed when the message would be processed , hence if you application is a client facing one or client is waiting for the response, that will bring in more complexity

You could evaluate if Akka framework adds more value to as you will get the following features out-of-the-box

1. **Event-driven:** Using Actors, one can write code that handles requests asynchronously and employs non-blocking operations exclusively.
2. **Scalablity:** In Akka, adding nodes without having to modify the code is possible, thanks both to message passing and location transparency.
3. **Resilience:** Any application will encounter errors and fail at some point in time. Akka provides “supervision” (fault tolerance) strategies to facilitate a self-healing system.
4. **Responsive:** Many of today’s high performance and rapid response applications need to give quick feedback to the user and therefore need to react to events in an extremely timely manner. Akka’s non-blocking, message-based strategy helps achieve this.

Comment: First, Thank you for your detailed response. I guess what makes me nervous is that arguably in the case you split one application into two and using Kafka as your async communication layer you need to split other services as well. Given you have 30 services that need to be resilient and highly available that means you have 60 services and a heavy coupling to your Kafka based communication protocol.

Comment: yes, your concerns are valid. Management of additional services is going to add complexity and orchestrating through Kafka will be a challenge. You can refer to this link for more details https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/microservices-when-to-react-vs-orchestrate-c6b18308a14c